# Type casting with non standard types in python

Tags: python, types, casting

How for example would I convert a type from some external class to another one? I've searched around, and gotten stuff like "int to string" and stuff, but I'm talking about something like class "tile" converting to something else, such as "tile2".

Comment: Could you give an example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel mentioned in his answer, **casting is not necessary in Python** because of the way code for Python is (should be) usually written. The thing you may need however, is **converting between non-standard types**.

Converting should be probably supported within `__init__` method within the class you want it to cast to, if you want to do it the way converting works for eg. `int`, `str`, `list` etc.:

```
class Tile:
    def __init__(self, val):
        # here paste the code making Tile object out of other objects,
        # possibly checking their types in the process
        pass
```

and then (after adjusting `__init__` to your needs) you should be able to cast it like that:

```
spam = Tile(ham)
```

More comprehensive example for converting between types:

```
>>> class AmericanTile:
    def __init__(self, val=None):
        if isinstance(val, str):
            self.color = val
        elif isinstance(val, BritishTile):
            self.color = val.colour


>>> class BritishTile:
    def __init__(self, val=None):
        if isinstance(val, str):
            self.colour = val
        elif isinstance(val, AmericanTile):
            self.colour = val.color


>>> a = AmericanTile('yellow')
>>> a.color
'yellow'
>>> b = BritishTile(a)
>>> b.colour
'yellow'
```

Does it answer your question?

Comment: Yes, that makes enough sense! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as casting in Python. That's because there's no need for it: generally, any function that accepts a 'tile' object shouldn't care that it actually *is* a `tile` rather than a `tile2`, as long as it has the data and/or methods that it is expecting. This is called duck typing, and is a fundamental part of programming in a dynamically-typed language like Python.

Of course, it is possible to *convert* from one class to another, but there's no generic way of doing this. Your `tile`/`tile2` classes would have to implement this themselves, probably by copying over the data elements.

Comment: +1 -- casting doesn't really make sense in the context of duck typing.